# Undertow returns data from directory

Tags: java, html, apache, httpserver, undertow

I'm trying to return local HTML files with an undertow server. The HTML files are located at `~/files/`.

For example, I've got the file `~/files/exp/test.html`. How can I return the HTML when I request `http://127.0.0.1/exp/test.html`?

Here is my current Server

```
  Undertow server = Undertow.builder().addHttpListener(port, ip).setHandler(new HttpHandler() {
        @Override
        public void handleRequest(HttpServerExchange httpServerExchange) throws Exception {
            httpServerExchange.getResponseHeaders().put(Headers.CONTENT_TYPE, String.valueOf(config.get("Type")));
            httpServerExchange.getResponseSender().send("Hello World!");
        }
    }).build();
    server.start();
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [ResourceHandler](https://github.com/undertow-io/undertow/blob/master/core/src/main/java/io/undertow/server/handlers/resource/ResourceHandler.java). You can use FileResourceManager or ClassPathResourceManager to help serve files.